# KineticJS: Setting Shadow on shape causing error in tween

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am creating pie chart using multiple Kinetic.Wedges and a tween that moves the pieces out.

This works fine, but when I attempt to add

```
shadowColor: 'black',
shadowBlur: 2,
shadowOffset: 10,
shadowOpacity: 0.5
```

in the wedge instantiation it bugs out - the error "TypeError: b is undefined" comes up. If I comment out the tween instantiation the shape loads without error (with shadows) so I suspect something in tween instantiation is causing it.

Here is code for this purpose.

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
container: 'container',
width: 578,
height: 200});

var splits = [{perc: 30, colour: "red"},
      {perc: 15, colour: "blue"},
      {perc: 20, colour: "green"},
      {perc: 35, colour: "yellow"}]; 

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
var startPos = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < splits.length; i++){
(function(){
    var wedge = new Kinetic.Wedge({
        x: stage.getWidth() / 3,
        y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
        radius: 70,
        angleDeg: toAngleDeg(splits[i].perc),
        fill: splits[i].colour,
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 1,
        rotationDeg: startPos});

    layer.add(wedge);

    wedge.tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
        node: wedge,
        rotationDeg: 90 + (180 - (toAngleDeg(splits[i].perc)/2)),
        x: stage.getWidth() / 1.5,
        easing: Kinetic.Easings.EaseInOut});

    startPos += toAngleDeg(splits[i].perc);

    wedge.on('mouseup', function(){
        wedge.setZIndex(100);
        wedge.tween.play();}
            );
     })()}
     stage.add(layer);
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: After some fixes to get your sample code running, I confirm that shadows + tweens result in an error: "unable to get property bufferCanvas of undefined...".  Submit an issue: https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues?direction=desc&sort=created&state=open

Comment: Dang - thanks for your help. After more playing I was able to set shadow using the setShadowColor method and run the regular tween without error but wasn't able to get it to tween the shadow itself.